# Output to Tkinter textbox does not appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to log some output instead to output it to the console, I want it to write it inside a textbox that I have defined.

The output should be in the `match-case` of the `proccess_input` function.

Problem is, I don't know why but nothing appears anywhere... It does not appear in the console or in the textbox. Not a single error is being raised.

I did a little bit of research and got to this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing


class Window:
    def __init__(self, WIDTH, HEIGHT, WIN) -> None:
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        self.width : int
            The width of )the window created.
        self.height : int
            The height of the window created.
        self.window : tk.TK
            The window object.

        Variables
        ---------
        self.data : dict
            A dictonary containing all information about buttons creates and titles displayed on screen.
        """
        self.width  = WIDTH
        self.height = HEIGHT
        self.window = WIN

        self.data : dict = {
            "Title" : None,
            "btns" : {}
        }

    def constract(self, title : str, background_color : str) -> None:
        """
        Creates the main window adds a title and a background color.

        Parameters
        ----------
        title : str
            A string which will serve as the window's title.
        backgound_color : str
            A string represents a hex code color (e.g. #FFFFFF).
        """
        self.window.title(title)
        self.window.geometry(f'{self.width}x{self.height}')
        self.window.configure(bg=background_color)

    def header(self, text : str, fill : str = "black", font : str = 'Arial 28 bold', background : str ='#E1DCDC') -> None:
        """
        Displays a title on the screen.

        Parametes
        ---------
        text : str
            The text which will be displayed on the screen.
        fill : str
            The color of the text, can be an existing color in tkinter or a custom hex code color (e.g. #FFFFFF).
        font : str
            The font type, the size of the letters and other designs for the text.
        backgound : str
            The color of the box around the text, can be an existing color in tkinter or a custom hex code color (e.g. #FFFFFF).
        """
        T = Label(self.window, text=text, bg=background ,fg=fill, font=font)
        T.pack()
        self.data["Title"] = text

    def logger(self, BG_color : str, state : bool = False, side ='BOTTOM', anchor='se', area : tuple = ()) -> object:
        # anchors - n s e w ne nw se sw center
        # state - TOP BOTTOM LEFT RIGHT
        if not area:
            t = Text(self.window, bg=BG_color,bd=1, width=self.width//50, height=self.height//40)
        else:
            t = Text(self.window, bg=BG_color,bd=1, width=area[0], height=area[1])

        # if not state:
        #     t.config(state=DISABLED)

        match side:
            case 'TOP':
                t.pack(side=TOP, anchor=anchor)
            case 'BOTTOM':
                t.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=anchor)
            case 'LEFT':
                t.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=anchor)
            case 'RIGHT':
                t.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=anchor)
            case _:
                raise(ValueError("Value should be a string and one of those: \"LEFT\", \"RIGHT\" \"TOP\", \"BOTTOM\"."))

        return t

class PrintLogger:
    def __init__(self, textbox):
        self.textbox = textbox

    def write(self, text):
        self.textbox.config(state='normal')
        self.textbox.insert(END, text)
        self.textbox.config(state='disabled')

    def flush(self):
        pass


def Move(direction, q):
    match direction:
        case 'left':
            q.enqueue('left')
        case 'right':
            q.enqueue('right')

def get_input(seconds, q):
    win = Tk()

    WIDTH, HEIGHT = win.winfo_screenwidth(), win.winfo_screenheight()

    main_window = Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, win)

    main_window.constract("AntiBalloons system controls", "#E1DCDC")
    main_window.header("AntiAir system controls")
    l = main_window.logger(BG_color='#E1DCDC')

    sys.stdout = PrintLogger(l)  # pass the Text widget to PrintLogger

    while True:
        try:
            win.bind('<A>', lambda event: Move('left', q))
            win.bind('<a>', lambda event: Move('left', q))
            win.bind('<D>', lambda event: Move('right', q))
            win.bind('<d>', lambda event: Move('right', q))
        except Exception:
            print('err')
            break
        #main_window.window.after(100, stdout_not_moving)
        main_window.window.mainloop()
        time.sleep(seconds)


def process_input(seconds, q):
    while True:
        if not q.is_empty():
            command = q.dequeue()

            match command:
                case 'left':
                    sys.stdout.write('Moving left')
                case 'right':
                    sys.stdout.write('Moving right')
        else:
            sys.stdout.write('Not moving')

        time.sleep(seconds)

# def stdout_not_moving():
#     print('Not moving')

if __name__ == '__main__':


    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_input, args=[0.1, q])
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_input, args=[0.03015, q])

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Comment: So this code is not the one that you wrote and you have problems with? It sounds like you just copied this from somewhere else.

Comment: See [ask]. Do a preliminary debugging at first. Then post a [mre] and debugging details. Anyway, running your code showed clear exceptions - "AttributeError: 'AutoProxy[Queue]' object has no attribute 'is_empty'" and "AttributeError: 'SyncManager' object has no attribute 'Window'".

Comment: @ovski No that not what I meant, I did in fact wrote 99% of the code myself. What I did tried to copy  is the part that logs everything to the textbox. 
This application is for my major in electronics, I ain’t that stupid to be questioned on something that I did not do.

Comment: As for @relent95, you get the first error because the queue is something that I wrote myself and it is in another file. For the second error, I could not see that but I will try to see if it appears. Edit: for the second example, the menagerie should not be in that part, I will update the code.

Comment: The instance of `PrintLogger` does not share across processes, so `sys.stdout.write(...)` in `process_input()` will not appear in the instance of `PrintLogger` created in `get_input()`.  Also you can just run `get_input()` in current process instead of running it in new process.

Answer (score 0):

If my first comment offended you I'd like to apologize. I just wanted to make sure this really is the code you wrote

I am only addressing the fact that you can't see anything in your text widget. There are other things that could be improved but this would exceed my time and this question.

But what stands out is that you restart your mainloop (and rebind your keys) inside a while loop over and over again.

so this is not needed:

```
    while True:
        try:
            win.bind('<A>', lambda event: Move('left', q))
            win.bind('<a>', lambda event: Move('left', q))
            win.bind('<D>', lambda event: Move('right', q))
            win.bind('<d>', lambda event: Move('right', q))
        except Exception:
            print('err')
            break
        #main_window.window.after(100, stdout_not_moving)
        main_window.window.mainloop()
        time.sleep(seconds)
```

instead try this:

```
    win.bind('<A>', lambda event: Move('left', q))
    win.bind('<a>', lambda event: Move('left', q))
    win.bind('<D>', lambda event: Move('right', q))
    win.bind('<d>', lambda event: Move('right', q))
    main_window.window.mainloop()
```

To test the console window, I added some print statements to your Move() function

```
def Move(direction, q):
    print(f'called from bind, direction: {direction}\n')
    match direction:
        case 'left':
            print('moving left\n')
            q.enqueue('left')
        case 'right':
            print('moving right\n')
            q.enqueue('right')
```

I changed the return of your logger() to tkinter.Text instead of object.

```
    def logger(self, bg_color: str, state: bool = False, side='BOTTOM', anchor=tkinter.SE, area: tuple = ()) -> tkinter.Text:
```

Please check this updated version of your code. You should see the console output in your textbox.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing


class Window:
    def __init__(self, WIDTH, HEIGHT, WIN) -> None:
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        self.width : int
            The width of )the window created.
        self.height : int
            The height of the window created.
        self.window : tk.TK
            The window object.

        Variables
        ---------
        self.data : dict
            A dictonary containing all information about buttons creates and titles displayed on screen.
        """
        self.width = WIDTH
        self.height = HEIGHT
        self.window = WIN

        self.data: dict = {
            "Title": None,
            "btns": {}
        }

    def constract(self, title: str, background_color: str) -> None:
        """
        Creates the main window adds a title and a background color.

        Parameters
        ----------
        title : str
            A string which will serve as the window's title.
        backgound_color : str
            A string represents a hex code color (e.g. #FFFFFF).
        """
        self.window.title(title)
        self.window.geometry(f'{self.width}x{self.height}')
        self.window.configure(bg=background_color)

    def header(self, text: str, fill: str = "black", font: str = 'Arial 28 bold', background: str = '#E1DCDC') -> None:
        """
        Displays a title on the screen.

        Parametes
        ---------
        text : str
            The text which will be displayed on the screen.
        fill : str
            The color of the text, can be an existing color in tkinter or a custom hex code color (e.g. #FFFFFF).
        font : str
            The font type, the size of the letters and other designs for the text.
        backgound : str
            The color of the box around the text, can be an existing color in tkinter or a custom hex code color (e.g. #FFFFFF).
        """
        T = Label(self.window, text=text, bg=background, fg=fill, font=font)
        T.pack()
        self.data["Title"] = text

    def logger(self, bg_color: str, state: bool = False, side='BOTTOM', anchor=tkinter.SE, area: tuple = ()) -> tkinter.Text:
        # anchors - n s e w ne nw se sw center
        # state - TOP BOTTOM LEFT RIGHT
        if not area:
            t = Text(self.window, bg=bg_color, bd=1, width=self.width // 50, height=self.height // 40)
        else:
            t = Text(self.window, bg=bg_color, bd=1, width=area[0], height=area[1])

        # if not state:
        #     t.config(state=DISABLED)

        match side:
            case 'TOP':
                t.pack(side=TOP, anchor=anchor)
            case 'BOTTOM':
                t.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=anchor)
            case 'LEFT':
                t.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=anchor)
            case 'RIGHT':
                t.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor=anchor)
            case _:
                raise (
                    ValueError("Value should be a string and one of those: \"LEFT\", \"RIGHT\" \"TOP\", \"BOTTOM\"."))

        return t


class PrintLogger:
    def __init__(self, textbox):
        self.textbox = textbox

    def write(self, text):
        self.textbox.config(state='normal')
        self.textbox.insert(END, text)
        self.textbox.config(state='disabled')

    def flush(self):
        pass


def Move(direction, q):
    print(f'called from bind, direction: {direction}\n')
    match direction:
        case 'left':
            print('moving left\n')
            q.enqueue('left')
        case 'right':
            print('moving right\n')
            q.enqueue('right')



def get_input(seconds, q):
    win = Tk()

    WIDTH, HEIGHT = win.winfo_screenwidth(), win.winfo_screenheight()

    main_window = Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, win)

    main_window.constract("AntiBalloons system controls", "#E1DCDC")
    main_window.header("AntiAir system controls")
    l = main_window.logger(bg_color='#E1DCDC')
    l.insert(tkinter.END, 'test text')

    sys.stdout = PrintLogger(l)  # pass the Text widget to PrintLogger

    win.bind('<A>', lambda event: Move('left', q))
    win.bind('<a>', lambda event: Move('left', q))
    win.bind('<D>', lambda event: Move('right', q))
    win.bind('<d>', lambda event: Move('right', q))
    # main_window.window.after(100, stdout_not_moving)
    main_window.window.mainloop()


def process_input(seconds, q):
    while True:
        if not q.is_empty():
            command = q.dequeue()

            match command:
                case 'left':
                    sys.stdout.write('Moving left')
                case 'right':
                    sys.stdout.write('Moving right')
        else:
            sys.stdout.write('Not moving')

        time.sleep(seconds)


# def stdout_not_moving():

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_input, args=(0.1, q))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_input, args=(0.03015, q))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

I am wondering, why are you using multiprocessing in the first place? All the changes I made will not fix the multiple tasks problem. Could you get rid of the multiprocessing or is it needed elsewhere?

**UPDATE: New code without multiprocessing, only using after and keypresses**

*This version is not based on your code, just an example*

```
import sys
import tkinter


class MainWindow(tkinter.Frame):
    WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
    WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
    TITLE_FONT = 'Arial 28 bold'
    COLOR_BG = '#E1DCDC'
    COLOR_FG = '#000000'
    LOG_INTERVAL = 100

    def __init__(self, root: tkinter.Tk):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.root = root
        self._is_key_pressed = False
        self._direction = None

        self._initialize_window()
        self._create_widgets()
        self._bind_keys()
        self._loop()

    def _initialize_window(self):
        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self._on_quit)
        self.root.title('AntiBalloons system controls')
        self.root.geometry(f'{self.WINDOW_WIDTH}x{self.WINDOW_HEIGHT}')
        self.root.config(bg=self.COLOR_BG)

    def _on_quit(self):
        self.root.quit()
        sys.exit(0)

    def _create_widgets(self):
        self._create_title()
        self._create_logger_window()

    def _create_title(self):
        tkinter.Label(
            self.root, text='AntiAir system controls', fg=self.COLOR_FG, bg=self.COLOR_BG, font=self.TITLE_FONT
        ).pack()

    def _create_logger_window(self):
        border = 2
        logger_width = self.WINDOW_WIDTH // 50
        logger_height = self.WINDOW_HEIGHT // 40
        self._log_widget = tkinter.Text(
            self.root, bg=self.COLOR_BG, fg=self.COLOR_FG, bd=border, width=logger_width, height=logger_height
        )
        self._log_widget.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        self._log_widget.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, anchor=tkinter.SE)

    def _bind_keys(self):
        self.root.bind('<KeyPress>', self._key_pressed)
        self.root.bind('<KeyRelease>', self._key_released)

    def _key_pressed(self, key_press):
        if self._is_key_pressed:
            return
        self._is_key_pressed = True

        match key_press.char:
            case 'A':
                self._key_move_left()
            case 'a':
                self._key_move_left()
            case 'D':
                self._key_move_right()
            case 'd':
                self._key_move_right()

    def _key_released(self, event):
        self._is_key_pressed = False
        self._direction = None

    def _key_move_left(self):
        self._direction = 'left'
        self._move_turret_left()

    def _key_move_right(self):
        self._direction = 'right'
        self._move_turret_right()

    def _add_log_message(self, log_message):
        self._log_widget.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        self._clean_log_history()
        self._log_widget.insert(tkinter.END, f'{log_message}\n')
        self._log_widget.see(tkinter.END)
        self._log_widget.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)

    def _clean_log_history(self):
        last_line_count = int(float(self._log_widget.index(tkinter.END)))
        if last_line_count > 30:
            self._log_widget.delete(1.0, 10.0)
            print('deleted logs from line 1 to 10', file=sys.stderr)

    def _loop(self):
        self._log_directions()
        self.root.after(self.LOG_INTERVAL, self._loop)

    def _log_directions(self):
        if self._direction:
            self._add_log_message(f'Moving {self._direction}')
        else:
            self._add_log_message('Not moving')

    def _move_turret_left(self):
        pass
        # inset code to move turret

    def _move_turret_right(self):
        pass
        # insert code to move turret


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    main_window = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer, first of all, it works well - I can see it being displayed in the console. But, the console stays always at the top and does not go down. Second and most important, you made it so that the `Move` function will display the output. I want the `process_input` function to output into the console. And as for the multiprocessing, I need to get and process the input at the same time, after I get t he key and direction of moving, a command will be sent via BlueTooth to my project which will move the DC motor that direction.

Comment: Lets split your questions up: If you want the console to scroll down you'll have to add it to the write method in your PrintLogger: `self.textbox.see(tkinter.END)`

Comment: I still cant see the reason why you would need mulitprocessing for this. Lets say you hit the "a" key, you want to have the log file out put "moving left" for as long as you hold the key and at the same time move your turret to the left? How does your bluetooth command work? Can you send it once and the motor keeps moving? I updated my answer with a completly new code that would do what I just wrote.